# ChartJS update chart with multiple datasets

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

So i want to update the 2 datasets in my chart (i don't want to destroy and then re-create).

```
chart2 = window.TrafficChart;
  chart2.data.labels = data.timestamps;
  console.log(data.traffic_tx);
  chart2.data.datasets[0] = data.traffic_rx;
  chart2.data.datasets[1] = data.traffic_tx; // fails here
  chart2.update();
```

When i try to set the second dataset `(chart2.data.datasets[1] = data.traffic_tx;)` then crash won't update (everything is empty).

Searched last 30 minutes for a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be old but I had the same problem and even after 2 years (of this question existing) I couldn't easily find a good answer. Eventually I did, so here it is, if not for anything else but for others to find it easier.

```
var this_data=[50,100];    //data to be loaded on the different datasets. this_data[0] to be loaded in dataset[0], this_data[1] to be loaded in dataset[1] and so on
var this_cntr;             //a counter to iterate over this_data


this_cntr= 0;
myChart.data.datasets.forEach(iterate);
//myChart.data.labels.push('label_name');   //these are to update the graph
//myChart.update('none');


function iterate(item) {
    item.data.push(this_data[this_cntr]);
    this_cntr= this_cntr+ 1
}
```

There probably is a shorthand version of this by I don't really care for shorthands.Maybe someone else can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of your `datasets` array.  If the second `data` key does not exist then create it.

```
let length = chart2.data.datasets.length;
if (length > 1) {
   chart2.data.datasets[1] = data.traffic_tx;
} else {
   chart2.data.datasets[] = {data: data.traffic_tx};
}
```

Or something more dynamic:

```
let length = chart2.data.datasets.length;
let i = 0;
Object.entries(data).forEach([key, value] => {
    if (i < length) {
        chart2.data.datasets[i] = value;
    } else {
        chart2.data.datasets[] = {data: value};
    }
    i++;
});
```